# Write Consistency Levels in DSE Search

Tags: solr, cassandra, config, datastax

I have Datastax cluster (2 cassandra nodes + 1 solr node) with secondary DC (2 cassandra nodes + 1 solr node). DSE 4.6.
Secondary DC id down (i had to turn it off due to hardware problems).
I want to change my solrconfig:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/index.xxxx/solrconfig.xml" --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

But I get error: *"CQL3 prepared statement failed after 4 attempts, source exception follows"*

In logs:
*Error Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM on attempt 4 out of 4 with CL QUORUM*

It seems that uploading new solrconfig require consistency `level:QUORUM`
(reload index too). Is there any way to modify this consistency level?
How can i modify solrconfig when some nodes are down?

Thanks
Przemek

Comment: try `?cl=ONE` per http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCL.html

Answer (score 1):

Resources like the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml are both written an read at `QUORUM` to maintain consistency. The `cl` HTTP parameter applies only to document updates.